# How do you install Ubuntu 22.04 via USB desktop when the monitor is connected to a display port

Tags: system-installation, usb, display, 22.04

The card is an AMD Caicos [Radeon HD 6450] and the monitor is connected via display port. When booting via USB, the monitor is never recognized, it never turns on, nor is enabled. How then do I install Ubuntu 22.04? Network install is currently unavailable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be sure to pull out my water colors and brush when updating the user interface (couldn't resist).

Network install is the only way to go rather than usb install for this case? Even a 600x800 resolution would work for a jumpstart. It seems to default to that when there's no custom driver installed after boot. Why not at boot time (for display port and hdmi)? Description says Radeon HD 6450 is a VGA compatible controller. My UI got messed up in a power hit and lost the config setup for network and display. Now on every boot, I have to manually configure the network and display via command line to get it to a usable state. I would like to install 22.04 via usb but can't because it won't recognize the display card until after the system is up and running, not at boot time.